# Print any document with a textual identifier on it

Tags: windows, language-agnostic, printing

Is there any possibility of printing any document (e.g. image, PDF, Office document, etc) with a text label at the top of page? Modifying actual files isn't an option for me. I'm wondering if there's anything like that provided in Windows printing system.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some printers allow you to add a "watermark" to every page they print (but that functionality is all in the printer drivers, now in Windows itself). If that's available to you, you could probably tweak the watermark to be what you need.

Another tactic--but a challenging one!--would be to create your own printer driver that accepts the Print command from any program, just like a printer, then adds the text label you want, then forwards the print job on to a real physical printer.